# UIWebView search with Google depending on local language

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

i'm using a `UIWebView` and i've got a `UITextField` getting a string that i'm converting in URL in this way

```
NSString *composedUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/search?q=%@",urlString];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:composedUrlString];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];   
[self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

What i want is to create dynamic URLs based on the set language of the device (or any other way round, **not** using some sort of GPS to get position), so that in `composedUrlString` i will have

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=
http://www.google.it/search?q=
http://www.google.fr/search?q=
http://www.google.de/search?q=
```

depending on the country. Actually i'm asking if there's a way to get the different `com`, `it`, `fr` to implement this code

```
NSString *composedUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.%@/search?q=%@",localLanguage, urlString];
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google can use the `hl` parameter to specify a language, however it will still use the .com site.

If this works for you, change the search URL, and use the device's locale to set the search language, like this:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com/search?q=%@&hl=%@", urlString, [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]]
```

If this is not good enough, you will have to create a mapping between locales and their corresponding TLDs and make sure Google is available on these TLDs. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) a list of countries and their TLD domains.

Comment: On simulator didn't work so i gave it a shot on the real device and was good!Thank you